# Convert ECC PKCS#8 public and private keys to traditional format

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve, java-security, pkcs#8

I have ECC public and private generated with BouncyCastle:

```
            Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

            ECNamedCurveParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable
                    .getParameterSpec("secp192r1");

            KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
            g.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());

            KeyPair pair = g.generateKeyPair();

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pair.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pair.getPublic().getEncoded()));


byte[] privateKey = new byte[]{48, 123, 2, 1, 0, 48, 19, 6, 7, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 2, 1, 6, 8, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 3, 1, 1, 4, 97, 48, 95, 2, 1, 1, 4, 24, 14, 117, 7, -120, 15, 109, -59, -35, 72, -91, 99, -2, 51, -120, 112, -47, -1, -115, 25, 48, -104, -93, 78, -7, -96, 10, 6, 8, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 3, 1, 1, -95, 52, 3, 50, 0, 4, 64, 48, -104, 32, 41, 13, 1, -75, -12, -51, -24, -13, 56, 75, 19, 74, -13, 75, -82, 35, 1, -50, -93, -115, -115, -34, -81, 119, -109, -50, -39, -57, -20, -67, 65, -50, 66, -122, 96, 84, 117, -49, -101, 54, -30, 77, -110, -122}

byte[] publicKey = new byte[]{48, 73, 48, 19, 6, 7, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 2, 1, 6, 8, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 3, 1, 1, 3, 50, 0, 4, 64, 48, -104, 32, 41, 13, 1, -75, -12, -51, -24, -13, 56, 75, 19, 74, -13, 75, -82, 35, 1, -50, -93, -115, -115, -34, -81, 119, -109, -50, -39, -57, -20, -67, 65, -50, 66, -122, 96, 84, 117, -49, -101, 54, -30, 77, -110, -122}
```

How to convert them into traditional format which can be reused later in https://github.com/kmackay/micro-ecc/blob/master/uECC.h? I need 24 bytes private and 48 public key while now it is 125 and 75.

Comment: What do you mean by "traditional format"? Is it PKCS#1 or you want to extract the parameters for the public and private keys?

Comment: I use secp192r1 curve so I need private key 24 bytes and public 48 bytes length.

Comment: Did you find way to convert pkcs8 EC keys to pkcs1 and back to pkcs8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gives 24 and 48, sometimes when 0 is added at the beginning 25 or 49:

```
    ECPrivateKey ecPrivateKey = (ECPrivateKey)privateKey;
    System.out.println(ecPrivateKey.getS().toByteArray().length);

    ECPublicKey ecPublicKey = (ECPublicKey)publicKey;
    System.out.println(ecPublicKey.getW().getAffineX().toByteArray().length + ecPublicKey.getW().getAffineY().toByteArray().length);
```